# Building GSA-Friendly AngularJS Application

Tags: ajax, angularjs, google-search-appliance

So we are just ramping up a new project to implement AngularJS in the most extensive way we have used to date. One of the concerns that has come up is regarding GSA's ability to crawl the website since we use it extensively.

Right now our implementation is as follows:

Step 1: JSP Returns page content from server with URL references for any AJAX feeds needed using a JSON object.

```
feeds: {
    "global": "href",
    "page": "href"
}
```

Step 2: Angular then makes an AJAX call to those feeds to get JSON objects containing page data.

Step 3: If the AJAX call is successful the data is attached to the root scope with the same name as the key for the feed.

```
$rootScope.global = result;
```

Step 4: The objects attached to the root scope are then used to build the site. This includes all dynamic data on the site which includes navigation (header and footer), page content, and more (pretty much everything on the page).

The main concern is that since all of the DOM on the page is being created by AngularJS and all data is loaded via AJAX that GSA won't be able to crawl the site correctly.

So far the only solution we have come up with is detecting if a page request is a GSA request or a user request, and just dumping the content on the page without styling if it's a GSA request, or otherwise following the above flow. I know that this is considered cloaking, but we use our own GSA in-house, this isn't for SEO purposes.

Is there a better way to accomplish getting GSA to work with an AJAX-heavy application without having to do twice the work like that?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  The GSA can in index javascript content on the page but will not index the rendered angular content.

Full documentation from Google can be found [here](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/admin_crawl/advanced_topics.html#1076182)

It sounds like the content is stored in a datastore, why not index it there with a display url which will be the click through url when the GSA serves it up?